# React - Invalid hook call when using package

Tags: reactjs

Recently I decided to integrate react-beautiful-dnd into my project. I wrote a bunch of code and it didn't work at all, the whole app doesn't get rendered and I get this error in console: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`
I started working on a problem and it turns out, I get this error, whenever I try to render **any** component from the package. It's not a problem with code or with the package, because people can run the same code without any problems, but I get an error.

So my app crashes even with this simple code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const App = () => {
    return ( // It doesn't render, I see only blank page
        <>
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            <DragDropContext></DragDropContext>
        </>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Did you read the rest of the "invalid hook call" error message? If I recall, it tells you some possible causes of that error such as multiple versions of React in your tree.

Comment: Yes, I read, I'm sure I have only one copy of React in app. Because when I remove `<DragDropContext></DragDropContext>` I get no error

Comment: Because you are not using react-beautiful-dnd properly.

Comment: What happens when you try and pass in children to DragDropContext? Is the error the same?

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-521903787) helps. Taken from a [Github issue](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1501) in the `react-beautiful-dnd` repo.

Comment: @msmoore Yes, error is the same. Also, here is the same code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hermann-cjbywb?file=/src/App.js). It works perfectly fine here, but I get error locally on my computer. Perhaps the problem is with my environment? I don't know :(

Comment: How are you so sure you have a single version of React? Did you look at `npm ls` / `yarn ls` (or verified that there's exactly one `node_modules/react` in your `node_modules/` tree)?

Comment: @AKX I just ran `npm ls react` and this is what I got: https://pastebin.com/PiaHVwYy

Comment: That result implies you don't have `react` as a top-level dependency at all? Do you have `"react"` in your `dependencies` in `package.json`?

Comment: (Also, _please_ don't start your projects in your user root directory! Give each project a directory of its own!)

Comment: @tomleb, guy suggests adding code in `webpack.renderer.config.js`. But I don't know where it is. Could you please point out?

Comment: @AKX Yes, I have react in dependencies there. Here's content of `package.json` file: https://pastebin.com/gTB7KHWD

Comment: @Daniil456 Right, so things are as I assumed from the get-go. That document shows you have React 18.x, and the `npm ls` output from before shows `react-beautiful-dnd` is using 17.x, and those are two different versions.

Comment: Furthermore, that package.json doesn't show you're depending on `react-beautiful-dnd` at all.

Comment: @Daniil456 Note the "bottom-line" of his comment. What he ultimately states is that he had "2 instances" of React running in parallel somehow. I haven't come across this issue myself so I'm not sure what to advise here, just added the post in hopes that it might hint at the problem in your case as well.

Comment: @AKX, hmmm. Maybe it's because I ran package installation command in user root directory? Maybe I should have done it in project directory?

Comment: ... Yes, of course you should have done it in your project's directory. Be sure to also clean up any stray node_modules/package.json/package-lock.json files from your user root directory.

Comment: @AKX, I tried installing package in project directory and got this weird error: https://pastebin.com/Yeq4tgcb

Comment: That's not a weird error, it's telling you exactly what's happening: react-beautiful-dnd declares it only supports React 17.x, not React 18.x. Change your package.json's React dependencies (both react and react-dom) to e.g. `17.0.2` and retry.

Comment: @AKX, So I changed both `react` and `react-dom` to `^17.0.2` in `package.json` in project directory and still unfortunately get an error while installing dnd package: https://pastebin.com/tczAxjzz

Comment: @Daniil456 Same error, similar fix: You will need to also downgrade `@testing-library/react` because that version doesn't support React 17. (Or, if you don't care for tests for now, get rid of that dependency.)

Comment: @AKX, Wow, it finally worked! Thank you so much for all your help! : )
But still there's one interesting thing to discuss: remember [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hermann-cjbywb?file=/src/App.js) piece of code? It somehow works however it uses **React 18**. How is it possible?

Comment: Because React components tend to be compatible (unless they use uncommon features) between React versions. You could have forced npm to install an "incompatible" version and it could have worked. Codesandbox doesn't do that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distil the comments into an answer:

- Make sure you install deps in your project's directory.
- Be sure to install compatible versions of dependencies, and to make sure there's exactly one React deduped into your project.
- If there are incompatible peer dependency versions, npm and yarn both will let you know how to fix the situation.